# MPI segmentation fault with MPI_Bcast communication

Tags: c, mpi

I have an MPI program which works fine if I use one node, and if I have multiple nodes with communications off it also runs fine (albeit with the wrong numerical result since the calculation needs the communication). However I get an address not mapped segmentation fault when I run it with communications.

I have cut down my program to the basic outline below. I have a struct defined outside my main program. We then have an array of these structs, this array of structs is divided amongst the MPI nodes, for example we may have 500 particles and 5 nodes so the first node operates on 0-99 and so on. However after each operation all the nodes need to synchronise their data, I try to achieve this with MPI_Bcast.

Is there a problem with using a global struct in communication between MPI nodes? Or why else might this communication structure give a segmentation fault.

```
#define BUFFER 2

typedef struct {
    double X[BUFFER];
} Particle;

Particle *body;

void Communication(int i_buf, int size){

  // there are N particles which have been operated on by the various MPI nodes
  // we seek to synchronize this data between all nodes
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int nbody = 0; nbody < N; nbody++)
  {
    // below returns the node number which operated on this particle  
    int node = IsNode(nbody, size);

    MPI_Bcast(&(body[nbody].X[i_buf]), 1, MPI_DOUBLE, node, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

}

void main() {

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int rank, size;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

body = (Particle*) calloc((size_t)N, sizeof(Particle));

  int adjust_a, adjust_b, a, b;
  adjust_a = Min(rank, N % size);
  adjust_b = Min(rank + 1, N % size);
  a = N / size * rank + adjust_a;
  b = N / size * (rank + 1) + adjust_b;


  int i_buf, i_buf_old;

  for(int i_time = 0; i_time <= time_steps; i_time++)
  {

    i_buf = Mod(i_time, BUFFER);
    i_buf_old = Mod(i_time - 1, BUFFER);

    #pragma omp sections
    {
      #pragma omp section
      {
        Compute(i_buf, i_buf_old, a, b); // just does some calc
        Communication(i_buf, size);
      }
      #pragma omp section
      {
      if((i_time != 0) && (rank == 0))
        LogThread(i_buf_old); // just writes to a file
      }
    }

  }
```

My full struct is:

```
typedef struct {
    double mass;
    double X[BUFFER];
    double Y[BUFFER];
    double Z[BUFFER];
    double Vx[BUFFER];
    double Vy[BUFFER];
    double Vz[BUFFER];
    double Fx[BUFFER];
    double Fy[BUFFER];
    double Fz[BUFFER];
} Particle;
```

Comment: What line is the segfault happening on?

Comment: I am not actually sure, it does say failing at address: 0x79 and another part of the error says "mpirun noticed that process rank 3 with PID 28129 on node murphc05 exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)."

Comment: It probably dumped a core file that you can plug into GDB to find out more about your error. Learning to debug your MPI (or any) applications is very important to being able to usefully write applications longer than 100 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using the wrong tool for the job. If you're trying to aggregate an array of data from all of the processes and make sure that all processes have the result of that aggregation, you should probably be using [`MPI_ALLGATHER`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Allgather.html).

This function does pretty much what you want. If you're in a situation where each processes has some data (an integer for instance) like this:

```
0)    0
1)    1
2)    2
3)    3
```

When you do the allgather, the result will be this:

```
0) 0 1 2 3
1) 0 1 2 3
2) 0 1 2 3
3) 0 1 2 3
```

If, for instance, you only needed the data to be aggregated in one place (such as rank 0), you could just use [`MPI_GATHER`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Gather.html), which would look like this:

```
0) 0 1 2 3
1)    1
2)    2
3)    3
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give MPI_ALLGATHER a try.I'll just need to rewrite some stuff to make the send and receive explicit. I was trying to use MPI_Bcast to loop over the array to force all processes to match the data of the root process which I was specifying for each element of the array, it sounds like this is not valid though.

Comment: With `MPI_ALLGATHER`, you won't need to loop over anything. You'll just do all of the data transfer at once.

Comment: I updated my question with my full struct that I am trying to synchronize between processors, would I still be able to synchronize this rather awkward data using MPI_ALLGATHER? I want to synchronize all values of n but for a particular value of i body[n].X[i]

Comment: Sure, you can send around any data you like. If you're going to be doing something like this, you might want to create an MPI datatype. That's way more complicated than fits into a simple comment. I'd suggest looking for some examples of MPI datatypes on the web.

Comment: I feared you might say that, I unsuccessfully played around with creating new MPI datatypes. I guess there is no avoiding it.

Comment: It's definitely tricky, but if you can get your head around it, it's quite powerful.

Comment: I've given this tutorial before and have slides available via my website (http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~wbland/slides/2013-06-10-argonne-mpi-basic.pptx). Feel free to take a look there. There will be a similar talk later in the week with code examples if you're still stuck.